# PHP a concatenate variable issue

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate several variables following http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php but I don't get why it's not working

```
<?PHP

$test1 = 'test1';
$test2 = 'test2';
$test0 = 'test0';

for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++){
    $j = $i%3;
    echo ${$test.$j};
}

?>
```

Comment: i don't see `$colonne` defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If at all possible it would be much easier to just set the variables up as an array in the first place.

But to do what you are trying do this

```
$test1 = 'test1';
$test2 = 'test2';
$test0 = 'test0';

for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++){
    $j = $i%3;
    echo ${"test".$j};
}
```

Comment: thanks, i'll use an array then, and your answer is working, so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
  $test1 = 'test1';
  $test2 = 'test2';
  $test0 = 'test0';

for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++){
$j = $i%3;
echo $colonne.$j;
}
```

?>

Comment: replace with variable which one you want concatenate.